# Alternative to setInterval that consumes less resources

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I have a component that changes images every 4 seconds like this:

```
state = {
  images: this.props.items,
  imageIndex: 0,
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => this.changeImage(), 4000)
}
changeImage = () => {
  const { imageIndex, images } = this.state
  if (imageIndex === images.length - 1) {
    this.setState({ imageIndex: 0 })
  } else {
    this.setState({ imageIndex: imageIndex + 1 })
  }
}
render() {
  const { images, imageIndex } = this.state
  return <img src={images[imageIndex]} />
}
```

The component is used in 6 spots on the page.

The problem is that after a couple of minutes, the fan goes on and the computer gets warm. I don't know if this is caused by increased `CPU` usage or memory leaks.

Is there any alternative method to `setInterval` (execute a repeated task at a predefined interval), while using less computer resources?

Comment: Do you want to each component have their own interval? One approach could be having just one interval and share the same interval with all the components

Comment: Does the component gets unmounted ? Is this always the same task  for the 6 different components ? You could create only one interval by making this.interval static and checking if it exists.

Comment: @FabioAntunes Yes, unfortunately they indpendent intervals.

Comment: @ChrisR I can not unmount the component as that would remove the images. But on your second question - yes, it's the same task for all components, but they have different intervals so don't think I can move it out.

Comment: Have you actually profiled this in e.g. chrome dev tools? `setInterval` consumes essentially zero resources, the callback it calls *might*. Maybe. Nor are we going to be able to help you much without more details about what `changeImage` actually does.

Comment: What does `changeImage` do?

Comment: Updated the question with the complete component to get the code context.

Comment: @JaredSmith You might be right, but including this component in 6 spots on the page **do** dramatically change the computer's performance after a couple of minutes.

Comment: @FellowStranger how often is react re-rendering those images? $10 says there's your problem (unless you have a `shouldComponentUpdate` you didn't post). Put a counter in your render method that increments and logs out to the console every time it renders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with using `setInterval` for this purpose. But you should make sure that you clear the interval when the component is unmounted! There is a function called `clearInterval` for this purpose. This could very well be the source of your performance issues.

So I suggest something like this:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```
function myFn() {
  setTimeout(myFn, 4000);
}
myFn();
```

Comment: `every 4 seconds` ? seriously?

Comment: @Manoj do you have a decent counter argument?

Comment: @castis,`setTimeout` is not appropriate in this situation as it will not work periodically.